# error showing x tick labels on shared subplots - 'silent_list' object has no attribute 'set_visible'

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

i'm trying to show xtick lables on the subplots through the following code

```
ax1.hist(x1, normed = True, bins= 50, alpha= 0.5)
ax2.hist(x2, normed=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5)
ax3.hist(x3, normed=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5)
ax4.hist(x4, normed=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5)

axs = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]
dis = ['normal', 'gamma', 'exponential', 'uniform']
for i in range(0, len(axs)):
    axs[i].set_title('x' + str(i+1) + dis[i])
    axs[i].set_xticklabels([])
    axs[i].get_yticklabels().set_visible(True)
```

I'm getting the following error in matplotlib

```
<ipython-input-2-d6371e87b196> in <module>()
     10     axs[i].set_title('x' + str(i+1) + dis[i])
     11     axs[i].set_xticklabels([])
---> 12     axs[i].get_yticklabels().set_visible(True)
     13 
     14 

AttributeError: 'silent_list' object has no attribute 'set_visible'
```

Comment: `set_visible` operates on a single tick, not on a list of ticks. Therefore, the correct way is `for t in axs[i].get_yticklabels(): t.set_visible(True)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  knew the way around just needed the conceptual clarity.